# How to animate an element's max-height from bottom to top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML menu element that I am currently animating using javascript and CSS. The menu's max-height is set to 0, with overflow: hidden.

```
<div class="menu">
```

The current CSS animation:

```
.menu {
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease;
    transition: max-height 0.4s ease;
}
```

In javascript, I am changing the menu max-height when a button is clicked.

This all works fine, except I would like to reveal the menu from the bottom to the top, instead of the top-down. Can this be done in simple CSS or JS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can transition `scaleY()` instead, and use `transform-origin`

```css
div {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
body:hover div {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: very elegant solution! Love it!

Comment: Note that `scaleY()` will distort the text.  The menu will appear to squish as opposed to slide.

Comment: @JosephMarikle If you mean "scales", then yes. However it solves the problem, which your solution does not exactly ^_^

Comment: @Christoph I wasn't meaning to offend.  My solution interprets the problem as the content sticking to the top or the bottom of the container as it slides.  I'm not at all sure that's what the OP intended.  I just know it's a menu, so I thought I should point out that text may look odd if you scale the container rather than leverage overflow hiding the content.

Comment: @JosephMarikle My comment came across to harshly, I am sorry for that! And yes, this is a valid point, that the font will scale as well! But I think it's the most flexible solution out of our three. Yours disregards the bottom to top part and mine works with positioning and heights which is a bit inflexible as well.

Comment: My menu only contains images, no text. Will this solution squish images?

Comment: Yes it will scale all contained content!

Comment: Gotcha, well I'll try it out and see which way looks best. Thanks everyone for being so helpful! (First time SO asker.)

Comment: I provided two other approaches which each have their unique advantages and disadvantages as well. If this scaling solution does not work for your, may one of those helps.

Answer (score 6):

Michael already provided a very elegant solution but it has the problem of scaling all content.

I just want to provide another approach: When using `position:absolute`, you can set `bottom:0` to make it reveal from the bottom. I used `height` in the demo, because it's a bit easier to get the dimension how you want them, but max-height generally works just as fine as well.

Advantage: content does not scale
Disadvantage: needs positioning and some fixed height declarations

Whatever works best for you.

```css
.menu {
    background:#bada55;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
.container:hover .menu {
    height:30px;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="menu">
  Menu content
  </div>
</div>
```

Another possibility is to simply animate the positioning. Here you just manipulate the `top` to achieve the sliding effect.

```css
.menu {
  background: #bada55;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding:10px;
  height:40px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  top:100%;
}

.container:hover .menu {
  top:0;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="menu">
    Menu content
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).  You would need to align it to the bottom using `align-items: flex-end;`.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.menu').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease;
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
  
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.menu.active {
  max-height: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle Menu</button>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4 (last item)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For reference, here is how the menu works without the flexbox aligning:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.menu').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease;
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
  
  background: #eee;
}

.menu.active {
  max-height: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle Menu</button>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4 (last item)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question I think your solution does not solve the problem;)

Comment: @Christoph I completely agree.  I feel like all three answers present have different takes on what the OP meant.